# how to bind dynamically dropdown based checkbox true in ng-repeat using angulrajs

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

hi all i am using angularjs ng-repeat i have checkbox and dropdown in inside the repeat now my need is when check the checkbox value i want bind the dropdown but now when i check the checkbox all dropdown values are changed but my need i want bind the dropdown based checkbox help how to solve

## ng-repeat code

```
 <div ng-repeat="BFMaterialStream in BFMaterialStreams">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-change="checkchange(BFMaterialStream.MaterialStream,$index)"
   ng-model="selection.ids[BFMaterialStream.MaterialStream]" name="group" id="BFMaterialStream.MaterialStream" />
    {{BFMaterialStream.MaterialStream}} 
        <select id="MaterialElevator" tabindex="7" required typeof="text" name="Elevator"
         form="DistanceMatrixFormId" class="form-control" 
          ng-model="ViewGetBUMaterialStream.ToElevator"
     >
     <option value=''>Select</option>
     <option ng-repeat="ViewGetBUMaterialStream in ViewGetBUMaterialStreams "
      value="{{ViewGetBUMaterialStream.ToElevator}}"
      >
     {{ViewGetBUMaterialStream.ToElevator}}
    </option>
     </select>
       </div>
```

check change time bind code

```
$scope.checkchange = function(Stream, index) {
     $http.get('/ViewGetBUMaterialStream/' + Stream ).then(function (response) {
           $scope.ViewGetBUMaterialStreams = response.data;
     });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `$scope.ViewGetBUMaterialStreams` as an array.

In HTML change the  repeat as

```
<option ng-repeat="ViewGetBUMaterialStream in ViewGetBUMaterialStreams[$index]"
      value="{{ViewGetBUMaterialStream.ToElevator}}">
```

In change your `$scope.ViewGetBUMaterialStreams = response.data` assignment as  `$scope.ViewGetBUMaterialStreams[index] = response.data`

JS looks like this:

```
$scope.ViewGetBUMaterialStreams = [];
$scope.checkchange = function(Stream, index) {
     $http.get('/ViewGetBUMaterialStream/' + Stream ).then(function (response) {
           $scope.ViewGetBUMaterialStreams[index] = response.data;
     });
};
```

Comment: super Thanks Mr.Amir Suhail.i am tried that way but i forgot to scope into array

Comment: No problem. Just a pointer, always its a best pratice to use ng-options instead on ng-repeated <option>

Comment: another query when i select dropdown i  need suto auto check in checkbox

Comment: what is main difference option and repeat

Comment: The main difference is when the select model bound to a non-string value, option wont able to repeat that. See docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43781667/how-to-auto-check-in-ng-repeat-check-box-when-i-change-dropdown-values
@Amir

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) directive:

```
<select ng-model="ViewGetBUMaterialStream.ToElevator"
        ng-options="stream.ToElevator as stream for stream in ViewGetBUMaterialStreams">
     <option value=''>Select</option>
</select>
```

#### [Here is a JSFiddle of a simple use case of ng-options](http://jsfiddle.net/derkoe/KN9xx/presentation/)

Comment: same yar because of ngrepeat ervery time i have to check the checkbox value will change all drop down