# how to auto check in ng-repeat check box when i change dropdown values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

hi all i am using angularjs ng-repeat i have checkbox and dropdown bind it now my need is when i change the dropdown values means automatically checkbox will check based on dropdown slection

```
 <div ng-repeat="BFMaterialStream in BFMaterialStreams">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-change="checkchange(BFMaterialStream.MaterialStream,$index)"
   ng-model="selection.ids[BFMaterialStream.MaterialStream]" name="group" id="BFMaterialStream.MaterialStream" />
    {{BFMaterialStream.MaterialStream}} 
        <select id="MaterialElevator" tabindex="7" required typeof="text" name="Elevator"
         form="DistanceMatrixFormId" class="form-control" 
          ng-model="ViewGetBUMaterialStream.ToElevator"
     >
     <option value=''>Select</option>
     <option ng-repeat="ViewGetBUMaterialStream in ViewGetBUMaterialStreams "
      value="{{ViewGetBUMaterialStream.ToElevator}}"
      >
     {{ViewGetBUMaterialStream.ToElevator}}
    </option>
     </select>
       </div>
```

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/2546/

Comment: can you make a fiddle of this

Comment: Please share plnkr demo of this code  , which will easy to understand problem and  people can help you easily without wasting  time to understanding where is the problem

Comment: ok wait i will update  my code @nair athul ;@kp chundawat

Comment: selection based checkbox checked @nair athul ;@kp chundawat i will update the fiddle

Comment: so when i select the 1 checkbox what value should i show in the dropdown

Comment: value shown in dropdown that not an a issuse when i select any dropdown value the relevant checkbox will be checked auto

Comment: I am not getting your question but I think is this your answer
https://jsfiddle.net/athulnair/pzuetsx1/1/

Comment: @NairAthul when dropdown select means checkbox will checked tick symbol will comes automatically that is my need .now clear?

Comment: so If you select any value in dropdown then automatically your checkbox should be checked isnt it?

Comment: yes right when dropdown selected value is select means unchecked that is my need

Comment: Okay making your fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-change on `<select>` and in the assigned function make the ng-model value of checkbox as true.

In checkbox HTML

```
    <input type="checkbox" ng-change="checkchange(BFMaterialStream.MaterialStream,$index)"
       ng-model="selection.ids[BFMaterialStream.MaterialStream]" name="group" id="BFMaterialStream.MaterialStream"
ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false"/>
```

In select HTML

```
    <select id="MaterialElevator" tabindex="7" required typeof="text" name="Elevator"
            form="DistanceMatrixFormId" class="form-control" ng-model="ViewGetBUMaterialStream.ToElevator"
            ng-change="SetCheckBoxTrue(BFMaterialStream.MaterialStream)">
```

in JS:

```
$scope.SetCheckBoxTrue= function (MaterialStream) {
   $scope.selection.ids[MaterialStream] = true;
}
```

Comment: any suggestions

Comment: try using ng-true-value and ng-false-value in checkbox

Comment: and also try to initialize selection.ids as array in begining of the controller, like $scope.selection.ids = [];

Comment: is $scope.selection is defined anywhere in the controller?

Comment: then in begin of controller do  `$scope.selection = {ids: []};`

Comment: No problem.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the fiddle for your working answer

https://jsfiddle.net/athulnair/pzuetsx1/2/

```
$scope.checkLine = function(index) {
    $scope.lines[index].selected = true;
  }

<div ng-repeat="line in lines">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="line.selected" /> {{line.text}}
    <select required typeof="text" class="form-control" ng-change="checkLine($index)" ng-model='line.text'>
      <option value='0'>Select</option>
      <option value='1'>one</option>
      <option value='2'>two</option>
      <option value='3'>three</option>
    </select>



  </div>
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot set property 'selected' of undefined i get this error

Comment: have you checked the fiddle

Comment: I have update the fiddle with selected property to the object https://jsfiddle.net/athulnair/pzuetsx1/3/

Comment: try to answer in my code it's not wokring @nair kindly update my posted code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43798329/how-to-insert-particular-array-value-in-mongodb-using-angularjs @Nair