# how to insert particular array value in mongodb using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I using angluarjs with mongodb.

I have schema is called `array based schema`.

**schema structure :**

```
var Schema = new Schema({
    UnitId: String,
    UnitName: String ,

    Details1:[{
      Details1ID:String,
        Name:String,
       Amount:Number 
   }],
   Details2:[{
        Details2ID:String,
        Name:String,
       Amount:Number 

   }],
  Details3:[{
      Details3ID:String,

   }],
```

I want query for inserting the `req.body` for only `Details3`.

how to do this?

*NOTE:Req.body is Dynamic value*

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to add `{ strict : false }` options to your schema

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // ..
}, {
  strict: false
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('MyModel', schema, 'myModel');
```

then create model with partial data

```
// Node.js server side
var model = new MyModel({
  // UnitId: "xxx",
  Details3: [...whatever]
});
model.save((error, data) => {
  console.log("model has been saved", data);
});
```

Comment: why strict false  what is the purpose of strict @aifarfa

Comment: says you need to save some dynamic values into the collection. for sample `new Model({ details4: [1, 2, 3] })` given that details4 is not defined in your schema it will be ignored when save. but with { strict: false } options everything will be saved.